# Generating html pages with mustache in a python CGI script

Tags: python, cgi, mustache

I need to deploy a static website to a host that allows ssh access and python scripts (via CGI). So far I used local generated html content with the help of mustache. So far so good. Now different people (with much less aptitude for command-line stuff) need to update the static pages. So I stuffed all .mustache files onto the server for shared access.

The challenge: I need to write a small Python CGI program that when started runs a mustache conversion to regenerate the static pages. It doesn't need to output anything fancy to the browser (some "Doing,filenames, done" would be enough).

So it needs to:

- be called from an URL
- Process all .mustache files and their headers to html

Basically convert this bash script into URL callable python:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Processes mustache templates into html files
echo "Commencing conversion"
for f in *.mustache
  do
       curfile=${f/.mustache/}
   echo "Processing - $curfile"
   cat parameters.yml $f | mustache > $curfile.html
  done
echo "Finished, check the results!"
```

How do I do that (Yes I admit: my Python skills are worse than my Mandarin)?
Just to be clear: I don't want to generate the pages when they are read or use a Python web framework, just automate the generation of the html

Comment: why not just run the bash script as CGI?

Comment: @MattDMo thx for stopping by. I would love to, but the hosting is hardwired only to run python scripts, no bash access (I didn't pick it)